# I want to generate a pdf file in java and put text on particular location

Tags: java

I want to generate a pdf file in java where I can put text on particular location and later print that file

Comment: Try pdfbox an open source pdf lib for java

Comment: Try pdfbox http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/cookbook.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you want to generate a pdf and then put text on it or you want to have a text file put text on it and then convert it in a pdf file?
I am not familiar with this but the approach I would follow is:
1) Create the file and add text to it
2) Convert this text file in a pdf file
3) print the file

Now, creating a file and adding text to it is easy, check bufferedwriter, inputstreamwriter etc. For the generating of the pdf I would say also to check the iText library.
Here are some useful links:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/78413-java-textfile-to-pdf-file-conversion/

http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/TextToPDF.shtml